# Comic book set in futuristic setting with reptilian humanoids

Tags: story-identification, comics

The title of this question is the best short description I can think of for this comic book/graphic novel series. I cannot remember the name of it, but for years I have been looking for it. I have tried googling, searching stores, and looking at online lists of comics matching that description.

The characters of the comic book were like reptilian and/or dinosaur humanoids, they were using what looked like modern day or advanced weapons. They were attacking a city/fortress and were also using large dinosaurs as beasts of burden to carry large weapons. This is the most I remember of it when I looked at it when I was younger.

Not to narrow the search in the wrong direction, but I feel like it was a Dark Horse comic. However, I have searched lists of Dark Horse comics to no avail.

I have tried looking through the list of dark horse comics and I have found nothing. It is not Age of Reptiles, Dinosaurs for Hire, or Dino Riders. I will continue looking. The only thing I can really add: The artwork looked modern (2000s) and they were using guns. Sci-fi guns but not laser guns. I really hope someone can help find it!

I scoured [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reptilian_humanoids) to try to find answers, but could not find anything. I remember they were using what seemed like ballistic guns but in a bigger sci-fi style. I also remember either large mecha or large dinosaurs carrying artillery. There may have even been a pterodactyl as the evil guy/boss. I had read it online and it was like a small sample or something. There were large beast carrying equipment and/or troop transports being shot at. I remember a few panels where the characters were all crouched in a hallway/alley way trying to get into the compound/city. The artwork was dark and the colors were saturated(?). This is all that I can remember.

I have been searching on a site like [this](https://www.comics.org/) with different filters to find it.

Comment: So the protagonists were lizard people? And were they attacking other lizard people? Humans? Something else?

Comment: Yes, all the characters were dinosaur/Lizard humanoids. They were attacking similiar humanoids. It was a more modern comic book and had a "dark adn gritty" theme to its art. I hope that helps!

Comment: Do you have a rough idea of *when* you read this? That would help narrow things down. Also, a confirmation that there were no humans (or other mammals) would help.

Comment: I feel like I read it in 2008 with a max range of up to 2012. Yea, there were no humans, or other things. I think it was a preview of a comic. They were attacking some city or fortress.  They had large beasts of war, and I vaguely remember a pterodactyl like villain. Sorry for the scant details! I try to write down anything I remember, and I hope this helps!

Comment: Weird, I was thinking of this last night and haven't been able to find the name. I think it came out in the early 90s? And I swear one of the characters was a triceratops. I recall the art looking a bit like Savage Dragon.

Comment: @Jhump I am not sure why my accepted answer is at the bottom, but I finally found the name! It is the Sigil comics! I will have to look up the Savage Dragon ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comics are called *[Sigil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(comics))*

[image: Front cover of Sigil Issue 24 showing a chained Saurian]

I randomly came across the Saurians from Marvel. Then came across these Crossgen comics. I scrolled through the collection, and this cover looked very familiar! Sigil #24. Also, Sigil #25 looks very familiar. I think I threw everyone off by saying dinosaurs, but in my defence, they ride dinosaurs!

[image: Front cover of Sigil Issue 24 showing a Saurian riding a dinosaur]

Now I just need to get my hands on these, and find the exact page I remember looking at...

Comment: Ah, I read the *Route 666* books. It's a real shame that Crossgen went bankrupt, ending their series.

Comment: Ah man! I didn't even know they went bankrupt! That is sad

Answer (score 5):

Could it be the Dino Riders comic, based on the [TV Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dino-Riders) of the same name?

It features the battle between two species, the good ones (human-like species) who befriend the herbivore dinosaurs and the bad ones (reptilian-like species) who use some brainwashing devices to control the carnivore.

[image: Picture]

Comment: This fits the description very well, however it is not it. The comic book or graphic novel I'm looking for is newer. Possibly from the early 2000s. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

It might be *Dinosaurs For Hire*.  It had humanoid dinosaurs using uzis.  They lived in a mansion and eventually attacked Dracula's castle.  I don't think they used other dinosaurs to carry weapons, though.

[image]

Comment: This comic seems interesting, however this is not it. The setting seemed to be on another planet, and the artwork was different. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Pool playing dinosaurs who attack Dracula's castle... Are you sure this is fiction? There is a History stackexchange you might want to post to.